# "Hard" problem: Given $n$ points and $m$ edges, how many different connections can you form?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

> Suppose you have $n$ points that you will connect with $m$ edges.
>   There must be a path from each point to every other point (not
>   directly, but it must be possible to get there somehow), and there
>   should not be more than one edge for any pair of points.
>
> How many connections can be formed with $n$ points and $m$ edges
>   given these constraints?
>
> $m$ will always be at least $n-1$ and no greater than $\frac{n\cdot
> (n-1)}{2}$.
>
> Example:
>
> Suppose $n$ is $3$ (points $a$, $b$, and $c$, and $m$ is $2$). Then
>   there would be $3$ possible graphs:
>
> $a$ -- $b$ -- $c$
>
> $a$ -- $c$ -- $b$
>
> $c$ -- $a$ -- $b$

I've yet to find a mathematical formula that will let me generalize this for $n$ and $m$, but intuitively, after solving for all cases of $n = 3$ and $n = 4$, it seems like there should be one. Is it possible?

Comment: For the simple case $m=n-1$ the answer is [$n^{n-2}$](http://oeis.org/A000272).